# laravel something went wrong in query or left join

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

There is two tables Attendance and Break. In Attendance table there are two column  `start_time` and `end_time` and these column `start_break_time` and `end_break_time` are in break table. also admin can change/modify any of time from attendance/break, I am cloning previous records into Attendance_Log and Break_Log table before edited.

I am using left join in AttendanceModel which is working fine when viewing current Attendance record which is came form Attendance and Break table, Also I have also added following condition for Current/Log Attendance

```
    if($url_seg_four =='log'){
        $attendance_table = 'Attendance_Log';
        $break_table = 'Break_Log';
    } else {
        $attendance_table = 'Attendance';
        $break_table = 'Break';
    }

    $attendance_query = DB::table($attendance_table)->select('attendance.*',
        DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(start_break_time,'"-"',end_break_time)) as break_punch_records') ,
    )

    if($url_seg_four =='log'){
        $attendance_query = $attendance_query->leftJoin($break_table,function ($breakleftJoin){

        $breakleftJoin->on('attendance.id','=','break.attendance_id');
        $breakleftJoin->where('break.log_id','=',$url_log_id);

        })
    } else {
        $attendance_query = $attendance_query->leftJoin($break_table,'attendance.id','=','break.attendance_id')
    }


    $attendance_query->get();
```

but the problem is that break_punch_records column null when I am viewing Log of same attendance and surprising thing is that when I get last query of Log Attendance and run it on mysql tool `break_punch_records` is showing with records value.

Note: I am also confused where that bug occur if there is error in query of log how records are correctly showing  with `break_punch_records` and if its error from laravel/php then how records are correctly showing in current attendance view.

Comment: Your current query seems to be invalid, because you are calling `GROUP_CONCAT`, a table level aggregate function, while also doing `SELECT *`.  Consider adding sample data for both tables and the expected result.  I view your major problem here as having to do with SQL, not PHP/Laravel.

Comment: Yea I have wrote that query roughly its pre written not copied from code :)

Comment: I got the problem on multiple where on left join. and fixed it.